# Probability; bridge hand question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

$13$ cards are chosen at random with no replacement from a deck of $52$ cards. 
find the probability there are $5$ spades chosen, $4$ hearts, $3$ diamonds and $1$ club.

I got $(13!/(5!*4!*3!))/(52!/(13!*39!)$
I'm not sure if I had this correctly or not but my answer seems to be way off.

Comment: Are you sure @ArchisWelankar?

Answer (score 2):

Choose spades: $\binom{13}{5}$

Choose hearts: $\binom{13}{4}$

Choose diamonds: $\binom{13}{3}$

Choose club: $\binom{13}{1}$

Choose ANY hand of 13 cards: $\binom{52}{13}$

Then, probability is $\frac{\binom{13}{5}\binom{13}{4}\binom{13}{3}\binom{13}{1}}{\binom{52}{13}}$

Answer (score 0):

According to wolfram alpha, your answer is
$$\frac{1287}{2267905570}=5.6748394510976045620805984439643137346322580794225925... × 10^-7$$
However, there are 13 choose 5 ways to choose spades, 13 choose 4 ways to choose 4 hearts, 13 choose 3 ways to choose a diamond, and 13 choose 1 way to get a club, and there are 52 choose 13 ways to make a hand. This gives
$$\frac{\binom{13}{5}\binom{13}{4}\binom{13}{3}\binom{13}{1}}{\binom{52}{13}} = \frac{635}{117859} = 0.005387794$$